# Aren't Recycled bottle candles in the public domain?

Tags: patentability, us20140234791

In reference to the patent: [US20140234791](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140234791)

People have been making candles from recycled bottles for years. Is putting a lid on the candle really different enough to warrant a patent?

Answer (score 1):

As noted by user4545, the linked document is a patent application, not a patent. You can check for the status on the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site. In this case select "Publication Number" and enter "20140234791". The status of this application is "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action" as of 06-10-2016. Looking at the transaction history, there were a series of rejections so I'm guessing the applicant figured out a patent wasn't going to be awarded and gave up.

To answer you specific question:

> People have been making candles from recycled bottles for years. Is
>   putting a lid on the candle really different enough to warrant a
>   patent?

Evidently putting a lid on a candle **is not enough** to warrant a patent, at least in the US.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that the referenced document is the publication of an APPLICATION for a patent. It has not yet been examined, nor has a patent been granted.